# Is using a Structure safe for Multithreading in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Class ReceiveFaxPrintHelper in c# that i implemented as Sealed. I have also implemented this as Singleton. I have a method PrintStoredFaxes defined in this class, which i protect using a lock.

The question i have is if i change ReceiveFaxPrintHelper from class to struct, does this affect my threading? Ndepend suggests me to change this to a structure instead of class.

```
public sealed class ReceiveFaxPrintHelper
{
    private static AutoResetEvent mJobCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private bool mPrintStoredFaxesInProgress = false;
    private object mLockPrint = new object();
    private const string mClassName = "ReceiveFaxPrintHelper";

   /// <summary>
    /// Function that prints the Stored Faxes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="o">completing the delegate message signature</param>
    public void PrintStoredFaxes(object o)
    {
        lock (mLockPrint)
        {
```

I use this like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ReceiveFaxPrintHelper.Instance.PrintStoredFaxes));
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between a structure and a class?  Because based on this question, it does not appear like you do, you might want to do some research on the matter.  If you want a single instance of your object you should be using a class not a structure.

Comment: Accept at least 80% of your questions for people to start answering you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NDepend is just misleading you here.  Singletons should not be structs.

However, there is no risk of such a mistake specifically breaking locking.  `mLockPrint` is not a struct and so copying of a struct it is contained in will *not* result in its duplication.  You could also make `mLockPrint` static if singleton behavior was intended for the lock but not for the whole structure.

Furthermore, as long as you use the `lock` syntax, you are relatively safe against accidentally locking a struct; that would just not compile.  The `Monitor.Enter` syntax is trickier, as it does compile which then results in silent disappearance of locking (more accurately, useless locking of boxed copies).

Answer (score 1):

It won't break your multithreading... but you should look at the actual differences in more detail:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109